# Initial task failed for action RecaptchaAction(action=signInWithPassword)

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies

I am using firebase for authentication , the signup is successfully working but when i login i got this error occurs, i tried everything  even i turned off the firebase 'email enumeration protection
but the error still remains same. Actually it do sign in but also same time give error.

> wa@gmail.com1212
> I/FirebaseAuth(22477): Logging in as wa@gmail.com with empty reCAPTCHA token
> W/System  (22477): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
> D/Linux   (22477): [Posix_connect Debug]Process com.ggsolutions.god_given :443
> E/RecaptchaCallWrapper(22477): Initial task failed for action RecaptchaAction(action=signInWithPassword)with exception - The supplied auth credential is incorrect, malformed or has expired.
> D/Linux   (22477): [Posix_connect Debug]Process com.ggsolutions.god_given :443
> V/NativeCrypto(22477): SSL shutdown failed: ssl=0xb400007ccbc49b98: I/O error during system call, Broken pipe
> D/Linux   (22477): [Posix_connect Debug]Process com.ggsolutions.god_given :443 .loginController:

```
class LoginController extends GetxController {
  //TODO: Implement LoginController

  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  Rx<User?> user = Rx<User?>(null);
  Rx<UserData?> userData = Rx<UserData?>(null);
  RxBool isLoading = false.obs;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    user.bindStream(_auth.authStateChanges());
    checkAuthentification();
  }

  void checkAuthentification() {
    print("I called");
    _auth.authStateChanges().listen((user) async {
      if (user != null) {
        print("Inned also called");
        await fetchUserData(user.uid);

        Get.off(HomeView(userData: userData.value!));
      }
    });
  }


  Future<void> signIn({
    required String email,
    required String password,
  }) async {
    try {
       isLoading(true);
      print(email + password);
         await _auth
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password)
          .then((value) async {
            checkAuthentification();
      });
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      isLoading(false);
      Get.snackbar('Error hai', e.toString(),
          snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM);
    }
  }

  Future<void> fetchUserData(String userId) async {
    try {
      DocumentSnapshot userDataSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .doc(userId)
          .get();
      if (userDataSnapshot.exists) {
        userData.value =
            UserData.fromJson(userDataSnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>);
      } else {
        Get.snackbar(
            "Error", "User Data not found for user- with ID : $userId");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error fetching user data:$e');
    }
  }
}
```

I am expecting to move to  the /home route after successfully Login but it keep giving error even after print that its login.